# What is the best approach to building an email alert service in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

I am looking to build a feature where folks can be notified via email when certain content is published on our website.  Users would provide their email address, select a few subject areas they are interested in and the frequency in which they want to be updated (daily or weekly).

What is the best practice for building such a system?

I figured I would start with some sort of Subscriptions table (postgres) that would have the following fields:

- email
- subject_areas (list of IDs?)
- frequency (daily/weekly)
- last_emailed (timestamp)

I could build a job that would run every night against this table which would hit each row and aggregate all content that matches the subject_areas they were interested in, generate the email and throw it into a 3rd party email service like Mandrill or Amazon.

Does this seem like a good approach or is there a better way to tackle this?

Comment: Why not just have the controller that publishes the content, trigger a rails mailer to send the email when the info is published?

Comment: Hi. This is a really interesting question but... Stack Overflow works best for specific, technical questions with a "right" answer. A general question  asking for an implementation approach is a bit too broad to work well here. We especially want to avoid extended, opinionated discussion on the "right way" to do something, because in the past, such discussions have turned into flame wars and had a tendency to tear our community apart. The only way to avoid this is to ruthlessly remove any questions that have that potential, so now we no longer allow such questions like yours. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables would likely be:

- Users (email, name)
- Subjects
- Subscriptions (user_id, subject_id, last_emailed, frequency)

The other part you want is a background job queuing system (delayed_job, sidekiq, or resque) that you'll put the jobs in.  A worker process will process jobs and send them in another process.

Cron and BG jobs go hand in hand

**Cron (or a scheduler).**

1. Find all users that have subscribed.
2. For each user - figure if there is new content to send them
3. Load up jobs for users that have new content to receive

**Background Worker**

1. For each user_subscriber_job - build email content based and user info and subscribed content
2. Send email out